# Ruby win32ole - how to pass a VARIANT parameter?

Tags: ruby, windows, automation, scheduled-tasks, win32ole

I am trying to automate the Windows Task Scheduler using Ruby.

I am using Ruby 1.8 under Windows Vista.

The RegisterTaskDefintion method of the TaskFolder object takes two VARIANT parameters for the username and password. Any attempt to pass a string into these parameters results in a 'method_missing' exception:

This does not work:

```
rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Task", newTask, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, 'user', 'password', TASK_LOGON_PASSWORD,  nil)
```

This works:

```
rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Task", newTask, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, '', '', TASK_LOGON_NONE,  nil)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a VARIANT?

```
WIN32OLE_VARIANT.new("Blah", VT_BSTR)
```

Comment: This is available in Ruby 1.9, but not Ruby 1.8. I was hoping to find a !.8 solution.

Comment: WIN32OLE::VARIANT::VT_BSTR