# Passing Null value to a COM function from ruby

Tags: ruby, com, vb6

I am writing an utility that creates Requirements in Quality Center using OTA (Open Test Architecture) api and ruby.

**OTA is written in VB and is exposed as COM functions.**

To create a blank requirement, we have to use a method called AddItem. The OTA document describes the addItem as follow:

```
Visual Basic
Public Function AddItem( _ 
   ByVal ItemData As Variant _ 
) As Object
```

ItemData:
Null. Creating a virtual Req object with Null ensures that you cannot then Post until all required fields are initialized.

My problem is, I want to pass VB's Null value from ruby to the addItem function. I have tried to pass nil but it is of no use.

Can anyone please help me to solve the above problem.

Thanks in advance.
Prasant Sutaria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function takes a Variant, so you are being asked to pass a "Variant Null". A Variant Null is a Variant initialized with the special type of VT_NULL.

I don't know how you do that in Ruby, but [with some help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/566190/2230) I can try guessing it looks something like this:

```
WIN32OLE_VARIANT.new(nil, WIN32OLE::VARIANT::VT_NULL)
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hi Euro, Thanks for help. Solution provided by you is working fine. Please find the working code for the above solution. addItem(WIN32OLE_VARIANT.new(nil, WIN32OLE::VARIANT::VT_NULL))

Comment: @user3098734, thanks for the correction. I have edited my answer with it.